# Jetty Server : Memory consumption issue.

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, embedded-jetty

We are running a JAVA web application with the help of jetty runner on a customize device board. The device board has some limitation like "SWAP disable"[RAM of 1GB], so whenever we start our JAVA webapplication with jetty, the memory consumption start from 350MB to 900MB gradually; 
Eventhough if we try to run a test application [simple html page with our application required libraries- websocket, jersey libraries, pdfbox, opencsv] the memory consumption in the range of 350M-900MB.

Our requirement that the memory consumption should not cross 400MB by JAVA web application. Need suggestion or solution on this issue. Is there any memory leak in jetty server or library?

Comment: I would try to run that software stack in some "lab" environment ... and well, do some memory profiling.

Comment: *"Is there any memory leak in jetty server or library?"* - Possibly, but it is more likely that the leak is in your web application. Have you tried looking for one there?

Comment: We have tested application with simple html page, without our code so still its consume in the same range..

Comment: List of library using in application -

Comment: amqp-client-3.5.3.jar
protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
gson-2.2.2.jar
jaybird-full-2.2.8.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.el-3.0.1-b08.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
javax.inject-2.2.0.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar

Comment: jersey-client-2.6.jar
jersey-common-2.6.jar
jersey-container-servlet-2.6.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core-2.6.jar
jersey-guava-2.6.jar
jersey-media-json-jackson-2.6.jar
jersey-server-2.6.jar
jetty-http-8.1.17.v20150415.jar
jetty-io-8.1.17.v20150415.jar
jetty-schemas-3.1.M0.jar
jetty-util-8.1.17.v20150415.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
log4j-api-2.3.jar
log4j-core-2.3.jar

Comment: org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar
osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
websocket-api-9.3.14.v20161028.jar
websocket-servlet-9.3.14.v20161028.jar
pdfbox-app-2.0.0-RC1.jar
opencsv-3.7.jar

Comment: Rethink Your architecture, dependencies for Your project are somewhat heavyweight, not typical for embedded programming.

Answer (score 0):

> [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html).  Consider upgrading.

Never mix versions of Jetty (or any artifact)

Your stated list of libraries (you can edit your own question, you know):

```
amqp-client-3.5.3.jar
protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
gson-2.2.2.jar
jaybird-full-2.2.8.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.el-3.0.1-b08.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
javax.inject-2.2.0.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
jersey-client-2.6.jar
jersey-common-2.6.jar
jersey-container-servlet-2.6.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core-2.6.jar
jersey-guava-2.6.jar
jersey-media-json-jackson-2.6.jar
jersey-server-2.6.jar
jetty-http-8.1.17.v20150415.jar
jetty-io-8.1.17.v20150415.jar
jetty-schemas-3.1.M0.jar
jetty-util-8.1.17.v20150415.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar 
log4j-api-2.3.jar
log4j-core-2.3.jar
org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar
osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
websocket-api-9.3.14.v20161028.jar
websocket-servlet-9.3.14.v20161028.jar
pdfbox-app-2.0.0-RC1.jar
opencsv-3.7.jar
```

Things to fix:

- You have two versions of Jetty: 9.3.x and 8.1.x (pick one, suggest 9.3.x)
- You have two versions of javax.inject: 1.x and 2.x (pick one)
- You have two versions of log4j: 1.2.x and 2.3 (pick one, suggest 1.2 as your slf4j-log4j12.jar library is using that one)
- You are using an outdated jetty-schemas.jar
- org.eclipse.jdt.core.jar is for JSP compilation on Jetty 8 (its inappropriate to see in your classpath)
- If you are not using OSGi, then remove osgi-resource-locator.jar

If the mentioned libraries are the ones you found in your WebApp's `WEB-INF/lib`, then the following jars should **removed** from being present in your `WEB-INF/lib` as they belong on the server classpath, not your webapp's.

```
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.el-3.0.1-b08.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
jetty-http-8.1.17.v20150415.jar
jetty-io-8.1.17.v20150415.jar
jetty-schemas-3.1.M0.jar
jetty-util-8.1.17.v20150415.jar
org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar
websocket-api-9.3.14.v20161028.jar
websocket-servlet-9.3.14.v20161028.jar
```